# Why do you install yarn and npm and other dependencies if you have docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've seen this type of install all over the place, but here's a perfect example:

https://github.com/austingray/react-express-graphql-boilerplate

> The install instructions are...
>
> - Install dependencies: yarn
> - Start the server: docker-compose up
>
> Now navigate your browser to http://localhost:3000/ and you should see
> the rendered Homepage component.
>
> - Watch changes to assets: yarn run watch

Can someone tell me why don't people include the commands "yarn" and "yarn install" and "yarn run watch" in the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml file?

I've always thought that the whole reason to use Docker was that you would not install dependencies directly on your computer and ONLY install them inside your docker container, but everywhere I look everyone always wants to install npm on your local machine, or php on your local machine, etc.?   Why???

Comment: I don't understand the question actually, In the github repo you have linked here there is a docker file which uses yarn commands, Docker lives to resemble the TEST environment, that is not your local computer (where you have developed) without the need of paying for a vm, and easy deployment. of course, If you are using a node app. you will probably need to install npm or yarn on the container.

Comment: Because prefixing every single command you might want to run with `sudo docker-compose run container name ...` is frustrating.  Also one of Docker's key design points is that a container can't normally access files on the host system, and depending on the host OS the bind-mount mechanism to bypass this can be slow or unreliable (you can easily find SO questions about live reloading not working in Docker).  IME it's much easier to use only host tools for day-to-day development, even if Docker is very helpful for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: @Shachar297 re: "you will probably need to install npm or yarn on the container"...  YES exactly, yarn, npm, and every other package manager should be installed inside of the container and ran from within the container.  Not installed on the host computer and ran on the host computer. I'm just wondering why I see so many that don't do it that way, like what am I missing?